# Failure loading tarball from GitHub to Heroku using Terraform heroku_build resource

Tags: heroku, terraform, github-actions

I am working on creating a CI Pipeline using Github Actions, Terraform and Heroku.  My example application is a Jmix application from Mario David ([rent-your-stuff](https://github.com/mariodavid/rent-your-stuff)) that I am building according to his Youtube videos.  Unfortunately, the regular Github integration he suggests has been turned off due to a security issue.  If you attempt to use Heroku's "Connect to GitHub" button, you get an Internal Service Error.

So, as an alternative, I have changed my private repo to public and I'm trying to directly download via the Terraform heroku_build Source.URL (see the "heroku_build" section):

```
terraform {

  required_providers {
    heroku = {
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }

    herokux = {
      source  = "davidji99/herokux"
      version = "0.33.0"
    }
  }

  backend "remote" {
    organization = "eraskin-rent-your-stuff"

    workspaces {
      name = "rent-your-stuff"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">=1.1.3"
}

provider "heroku" {
  email   = var.HEROKU_EMAIL
  api_key = var.HEROKU_API_KEY
}

provider "herokux" {
  api_key = var.HEROKU_API_KEY
}

resource "heroku_app" "eraskin-rys-staging" {
  name        = "eraskin-rys-staging"
  region      = "us"
}
    
resource "heroku_addon" "eraskin-rys-staging-db" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.eraskin-rys-staging.id
  plan       = "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
}
    
resource "heroku_build" "eraskin-rsys-staging" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.eraskin-rys-staging.id
  buildpacks = ["heroku/gradle"]
  source {
    url      = "https://github.com/ericraskin/rent-your-stuff/archive/refs/heads/master.zip"
  }
}
    
resource "heroku_formation" "eraskin-rsys-staging" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.eraskin-rys-staging.id
  type       = "web"
  quantity   = 1
  size       = "Standard-1x"
  depends_on = [heroku_build.eraskin-rsys-staging]
}
```

Whenever I try to execute this, I get the following build error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

 !     Push rejected, Failed decompressing source code.
Source archive detected as: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

More information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs#create-slug-archive
```

My assumption is that Heroku can not download the tarball, but I can successfully download it without any authentication using wget.

How do I debug this?  Is there a way to ask Heroku to show the commands that the build stack is executing?

For that matter, is there a better approach given that the normal GitHub integration pipeline is broken?

Comment: You should probably use releases as described here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/heroku/heroku/latest/docs/resources/build#github-urls.

Comment: True, but the documentation says you can reference the master branch directly if you choose.  It is just harder to make sure that the code you build is actually the one you intended.  Since this is just a proof of concept, I'm not worried about it yet.  Unless you are implying that this is the actual issue?

Comment: I am not implying anything as this is the first time I even opened the provider docs for Heroku, just trying to be helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this issue, based on the notes from Heroku.  They suggest using a third-party GitHub Action [Deploy to Heroku](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku) instead of Terraform.  To use it, I removed my heroku_build and heroku_formation from my main.tf file, so it just contains this:

```
resource "heroku_app" "eraskin-rys-staging" {
  name        = "eraskin-rys-staging"
  region      = "us"
}

resource "heroku_addon" "eraskin-rys-staging-db" {
  app_id     = heroku_app.eraskin-rys-staging.id
  plan       = "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
}
```

My GitHub workflow now contains:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
        run: terraform fmt

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Validate
        id:  validate
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
        run: terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
        run: terraform plan -no-color -input=false
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Update Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          PLAN: "terraform\n${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        with:
          script: |
            const output = `#### Terraform Format and Style \`${{ steps.fmt.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Initialization ️⚙️\`${{ steps.init.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Plan \`${{ steps.plan.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Validation \`${{ steps.validate.outcome }}\`
      
            <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>
      
            \`\`\`\n
            ${process.env.PLAN}
            \`\`\`
      
            </details>
      
            *Pusher: @${{ github.actor }}, Action: \`${{ github.event_name }}\`*`;
      
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })

      - name: Terraform Plan Status
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
        run: exit 1

      - name: Terraform Apply
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event_name == 'push'
        working-directory: ./infrastructure
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false

  heroku-deploy:
    name: 'Heroku-Deploy'
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: terraform
    steps:
      - name: Checkout App
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Deploy to Heroku
        uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: ${{secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME}}
          heroku_email: ${{secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL}}
          buildpack:  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle.git
          branch: master
          dontautocreate: true
```

The workflow has two "phases".  On the pull request, it runs the tests in my application, followed by terraform fmt, terraform init and terrform plan.  On a merge to my master branch, it runs the terraform apply.  When that completes, it runs the second job that runs the akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 GitHub action.

As far as I can tell, it works.  YMMV, of course. ;-)